# Why do transitive dependencies flow to parent projects by default in .NET Core?

Tags: .net, architecture, nuget, csproj

In the solution shown below, `Newtonsoft.Json` is available to the parent project, `Transitive.Console`, as a transitive dependency via the project reference to `Transitive.Library`. Both projects target .NET 6.0.

[image: solution explorer]

At first glance this seems handy, but when I think again it seems like it could cause some issues where dependencies start to leak out into parent projects when they probably shouldn't.

My instinct is to hide everything away with `<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>`, but I'm doubting myself and wondering why I would be so blatantly swimming against this transitive tide when it's the default behaviour?

I've searched, but cannot find why this behaviour was introduced. The .NET Framework doesn't behave like this.

What are the benefits of automatically allowing transitive dependencies to flow to parent projects? What will I be missing out on if I indiscriminately slap `<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>` everywhere?

Comment: I think we've seen both of the alternatives - project references where you had to manually track and apply any necessary dependencies or Nuget adding all of the dependencies to your config as if you'd chosen to install all of them for this project. I tend to think the current behaviour is the "least worst" variant that's been tried so far.